# See if items in a string list contain a certain string

Tags: c#, string

Basically i have a string list as such:

```
/forum/
/phpld/
/php/
```

Now i want to check if any of the url:
http://www.url.com/forum/

contains any values from the string list.

In the above case it should match because /forum/ is in the url.

I was thinking something like this:

```
foreach (string filter in _filterList)
{
    if (PAGEURL.Trim().Contains(filter.Trim()))
    {
        _parseResultsFinal.Add(PAGEURL);
        filteredByURL++;
        break;
    }
}
```

But i cannot get the above to be accurate 
How would i do this? :)

Comment: What do you mean for 'accurate'. Missing match if upper/lower case or whatelse?

Comment: Yes, what's not working? The code looks fine for the problem you've described, at least to me.

Comment: wondering if there is a more optimized way to do it, the above seems to give inaccurate results for some reason

Comment: Can you give an example of input data that gives inaccurate results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
_filterList.Any(filter => PAGEURL.Trim().Contains(filter.Trim()));
```

You may do `PAGEURL = PAGEURL.Trim()` before this expression to not run it each time.

Comment: Doesn't have to be any more complicated than this.

Comment: Upvoted for its simplicity. But as @chamila_c pointed out, this solution is case sensitive. Which wasn't stated as being an concern in the question, but worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 1):

String.Contains() is case-sensitive and culture-insensitive, so if there are any case differences that could be the cause of the 'inaccuracy' that you are experiencing.

If you suspect this may be the problem (or even as a viable alternative) you can try this as the 'if' clause:

`if (PAGEURL.Trim().IndexOf(filter.Trim(),  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not abundantly clear on what you want to do here, it seems as though if a URL contains any of the filters then you want to add the URL to the list.

```
List<string> parseResultsFinal = new List<string>();
if (_filterList.Any(x => PAGEURL.Contains(x))
{
   parseResultsFinal.Add(PAGEURL);
}
```

Try to use that.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
var trimmedUrl = PageURL.Replace("http://", "");
var parts = trimmedUrl.Split("/");

var filterList = new List<string> { "forum", "phpld", "php" }

var anyContains = parts.Any(o => filterList.contains(o));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd change segments filters to simple words (without slashes, trimmed *before* adding to filter list):

```
var _filterList = new List<string>()
{
    "forum", "phpld", "php"
};
```

And used regex to search for segments in url (ignore case, optional slash at the end of url)

```
bool IsSegmentInUrl(string url, string segment)
{
    string pattern = String.Format(".*/{0}(/|$)", segment);
    return Regex.IsMatch(url, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Usage:

```
if (_filterList.Any(filter => IsSegmentInUrl(PAGEURL, filter))
{
      _parseResultsFinal.Add(PAGEURL);
      filteredByURL++;
}
```

---

More readable solution - create extensions method

```
public static bool ContainsSegment(this string url, string segment)
{
    string pattern = String.Format("http://.*/{0}(/|$)", segment);
    return Regex.IsMatch(url, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Now code looks very self-describing:

```
if (_filterList.Any(filter => PAGEURL.ContainsSegment(filter))
{
      _parseResultsFinal.Add(PAGEURL);
      filteredByURL++;
}
```

Comment: If using a Regex couldn't you build the regex from the `_filterList` and do it in one. I'm not a regex person so this is probably wrong but something like `string.format("http://.*/({0})(/|$)", string.Join(_filterList, "|"));`.